# The 'prime logarithm'

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, functional-equations

Lately I've been thinking about the functional equation $$f(ab) = f(a) + f(b)$$ but not in the usual sense where continuity or differentiability are assumed. It's clear that $f(1) = 0$, by letting $a = b = 1$. It is also clear, that given any natural number $n = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_m^{a_m}$ that $f(n) = a_1f(p_1) + a_2f(p_2) + ... + a_mf(p_m)$.

Consider the function $\ell:\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb N$ such that it is a solution to the functional equation, and $\ell(p) = p$ when $p$ is prime.

Some example values:
$$\ell(1) = 0\\\ell(2) = 2\\\ell(15) = \ell(5) + \ell(3) = 8\\\ell(264) = 3\ell(2) + \ell(3) + \ell(11) = 20$$

Here is a plot of the function for $1 \leq n \leq 1000$:
[image]

---

So my question is, does this function have a name? Does it have any useful purpose, or interesting properties? It seems we can extend the domain of this function to the positive rational numbers, making the range $\mathbb Z$ rather than $\mathbb N$.
Some values if we extend to rational numbers:

$$\ell\left(\frac12\right) = -2\\\ell\left(\frac{7}{9}\right) = \ell(7) - 2\ell(3) = 1 \\\ell\left(\frac{42}{110}\right) = \ell(2) + \ell(3) + \ell(7) - \ell(11)-\ell(5) - \ell(2) = -6$$

Notice how the common factors cancelled out in the last example without having to simplify the fraction, showing that $\ell$ is well defined for all $n \in \mathbb Q^+\setminus\{0\}$.

<sub>* I made the graph quickly on excel, please feel free to replace it with a better one.</sub>

Comment: you should consider instead $g(n) = \sum_{p^k | n} \frac{p^k}{k}$, it is very close, still additive : $g(ab) = g(a)+g(b)$ whenever $gcd(a,b)$ (i.e. $e^{g(n)}$ is a  [multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function)) and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n) n^{-s} = (\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s})(\sum_{p^k} \frac{p^k}{k} p^{-sk}) = \zeta(s) \ln \zeta(s-1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\ell$ on $\Bbb N$ is the *[sum of prime factors (function)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofPrimeFactors.html)*, or a little less literally, the *integer logarithm*.

P.A. MacMahon calls $ell(n)$ the *potency* of $n$ (see P.A. MacMahon, [*Properties of Prime Numbers Deduced from the Calculus of Symmetric Functions*](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-23/1/290.extract), Proc. London Math. Soc. (1925) s2-23 (1): 290-316.)

The values $\ell(1), \ell(2), \ldots$ are the content of OEIS [A001414](http://oeis.org/A001414), and this sequence has [its own OEIS Wiki page](https://oeis.org/wiki/Sum_of_prime_factors_of_n_(with_multiplicity)).

Note that the extended map on $\Bbb Q_+$ is a group homomorphism $(\Bbb Q_+, \,\cdot\,) \to (\Bbb Z, +)$.

Comment: That's really helpful! Any info on the rational version?

Comment: I haven't seen a name for it. As you point out it's the union function on $\Bbb Q - \{0\}$ extending the integer logarithm that satisfies the given functional equation. If you were writing about it, you could just call it the integer logarithm anyway, with an explanation note about your usage.

Comment: $g(n) = \sum_{p^k | n} \frac{p^k}{k}$ (also an additive function) is close to it and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n) n^{-s} = \zeta(s) \ln \zeta(s-1)$, while $\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(n) n^{-s} = \zeta(s) \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(m)}{m} \ln \zeta(ms-1)$ (with $l(n) = \sum_{p | n} p$)

Comment: Of course, I mean $\Bbb Q_+$ in previous comment.

Comment: A small, tiny comment: I have a lecturer who complains that the notation $\mathrm{foo}_+$ is ambiguous, and that he often cannot tell whether or not $0$ is included in the relevant set, and he advocates the notations $\mathrm{foo}_{\geq 0}$ and $\mathrm{foo}_{> 0}$ for this reason. For instance, the positive rationals would be $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ in this notation.

Answer (score 1):

Long comment:

The commutative monoid $(\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\},\times,1)$ is freely generated (as a commutative monoid) by the prime numbers. In other words, for any commutative monoid $X$ and any function $f:\mathbb{P} \rightarrow X$, there's a unique homomorphism $\hat{f}:(\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\},\times,1) \rightarrow X$ such that the restriction of $\hat{f}$ to $\mathbb{P}$ is $f.$

- Your function is $\hat{f}$ for the special case where $X = (\mathbb{N},+,0)$ and $f:\mathbb{P} \rightarrow X$ is defined by $f(p) = p$.
- If instead of adding prime factors, you just want $\hat{f}$ to count them, take $f(p) = 1$ instead.
- If you want $\hat{f}$ to compute the [radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) of a number, take $X = (\mathbb{N},\mathrm{lcm},1)$ and $f(p) = p$.
- If you want $\hat{f}$ to tell you the largest prime in the factorization, take $X=(\mathbb{P},\mathrm{max},2)$ or $X = (\mathbb{N},\mathrm{max},0)$, either one, and define $f(p) = p$.

I find these kinds of functions super-cool, by the way.

Also, note that $(\mathbb{Q}_{>0},\times,1)$ is the commutative group freely generated by $\mathbb{P}$. So you can do similar stuff in that context.

---

**Addendum.**

Also, note that for all $a,b \geq 2$, we have $a+b \leq ab$. Hence if $\hat{f}$ is the function you're interested in, then $\hat{f}(n) \leq n$. So letting $n \geq 2$ denote be fixed, we see that the sequence $$(n,\hat{f}(n),\hat{f}(\hat{f}((n)),\ldots)$$ is eventually constant. Two obvious questions are:

- How many steps before its constant?
- What is the final value of this sequence? (I think it will always be prime.)

For example, applying $\hat{f}$ repeatedly to $15$, we get:

$$15 \mapsto 8 \mapsto 6 \mapsto 5 \mapsto 5 \mapsto 5 \mapsto \cdots$$

so it takes $3$ steps and we stabilize at $5$.

Kind of cool, huh? This gives us a potentially interesting way of assigning to each element of $\mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$ a prime number (e.g. to $15$ we assign $5$.) We might write $\hat{f}^{\infty}(15) = 5$ or something like that. Perhaps this number tells us something important about the structure of the number we started with.

Comment: I don't get your message... can you start with defining $\hat{f}$ please ? and writing exactly what means the morphism of monoids ($\hat{f}(ab) = \hat{f}(a)\hat{f}(b)$ whenever $gcd(a,b) = 1$ ??)

Comment: Who would downvote this?

Comment: @user1952009, a morphism of monoids $\varphi : A \rightarrow B$ is just a function $\varphi$ satisfying: $$\varphi(aa') = \varphi(a)\varphi(a'), \qquad \varphi(1) = 1.$$ What I'm basically saying is that your function can be characterized as the unique function $\hat{f} : \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ satisfying: $$\hat{f}(ab) = \hat{f}(a)+\hat{f}(b), \quad \hat{f}(1) = 0$$ that also satisfies: for all prime $p$, we have $\hat{f}(p) = p$.

Comment: You could pose a separate question about some aspect of $\hat{f}^{\infty}$.